# Object doesn't seem to load with all of its properties. - Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have two js files on my node server that require each other.
both have objects that are exposed via the `module.exports` mechanism.

1st file is located under `bl/commands.js` and uses:

```
var smUtil = require('./../utils/smUtil');
```

2nd file is located under `utils/smUtil.js` and uses:

```
var commands = require('./../bl/commands');
```

When a function runs from `smUtil.js` and uses some properties of `commands.js` it seems like `command` is an empty object and the import was not successful.

Here is the catch, when i remove the `require` of `smUtil` form inside `commands.js` everything works, which makes me think that i'm doing a newbe mistake.

Any thoughts?

Comment: i found this article:
https://coderwall.com/p/myzvmg/circular-dependencies-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

[Node.js documentation about circular dependencies](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles)

You are absolutely right that empty objects are returned.

To Quote Node.js documentation

> When main.js loads a.js, then a.js in turn loads b.js. At that point, b.js tries to load a.js. In order to prevent an infinite loop, an unfinished copy of the a.js exports object is returned to the b.js module. b.js then finishes loading, and its exports object is provided to the a.js module.

A solution could be to create a separate file to require both the files there and instantiate that file to avoid the circular dependency.

Comment: upvoted :), I'm going to post an answer which solved my problem, it would be great if you could explain some more regarding my solution and why my solution is NOT the best one.

Answer (score 0):

The specific solution which solved my problem was to place `var smUtil = require('./../utils/smUtil');` Underneath the `module.exports` inside `commands.js`.

However i feel like this solution is not the best one out there.

Thanks to the author of:
 coderwall.com/p/myzvmg/circular-dependencies-in-node-js